# Open specific View Controller in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have implemented `firebase notification` in my app. When I click the notification i want to open specific vc. The hierarchy of vc is this,

> TabBarController -> TabBarVC1 -> 1VC -> 2VC

Now, I want to go to 2VC when I click the notification. I have tried the code it goes fine but the hierarchy of VC's disturbs, when I moves there then it does not comes back. This is how i open 2VC.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "2VC")
self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I want it to open 2VC but its hierarchy should not be disturb.
When I click back button on 2VC than it should move back to 1VC.

Comment: Are you saying you want to `push` the view controller instead of `present`? Even if you `present`, the previous view controller would be there if you dismiss it.

Comment: No i want to open 2VC when clicked and when i move back it should follow the hierarchy. @RakeshaShastri

Answer (score 0):

To have a back button then you need to make the root vc of the tabBar a navigationController

> Entry Point -> TabBar ->  Tab1 -> NavigationController - > VC1 -> VC2

then use this from vc1

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc2, animated: true)
```

if you want to open it from AppDelelgate call back of notification receive  then use

```
if let tab = self.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
 let vc1 = //////
 let vc2 = //////
 let nav = tab.viewControllers![0] as! UINavigationController
 nav.viewControllers = [vc1,vc2]
}
```

Comment: I directly wana open VC2 but hierarchy should be maintain.@Sh_Khan

Comment: where you wan to run this code ?? , also why not change the hierarchy ?

Comment: I open my tab1 like this,
let tabBarController = UIStoryboard().loadTabBarController()
            tabBarController.selectedIndex = TabBarItems.HOME.rawValue
            self.present(tabBarController, animated: false, completion: nil). @Sh_Khan

Comment: This code will run in app delegate when i click the firebase notification. @Sh_Khan

Comment: In appdelegate class. when i receive notification. @Sh_Khan

Comment: present won't wok in app delegate try my second block of code

Comment: let me try. @Sh_Khan

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
let vc1 = // alloc vc 1
let vc2 = // alloc vc 2
let vc3 = // alloc vc 3
let nav_Controllr = // alloc UINavigationController

// Now add your previous vc in NavigationController first
nav_Controllr.viewControllers.append(vc1)
nav_Controllr.viewControllers.append(vc2)

// Now push to the vc where you wanted navigate
nav_Controllr.pushViewController(vc3, animated: true)
```

Now your navigation stack is like this

```
vc1 -> vc2 -> vc3
```

when you pop your controller then it always be in this flow.

```
vc3 => vc2 => vc1
```

Comment: According to your example vc1 is my tab bar controller index1 vc. How i can access that. @dahiya_boy